# How Add a formula(Dynamic value of cell) in Excel Using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

[image]

I have above scenario where i need add sum formula for column `C`,`D`,`E` as total where row can be increased or decreased. I have followed some links but not able find a solution as i know we need specify `sum(X1:Xn)` value so here i need those value to be dynamic so how can i achieve this. Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the below:

```
cell.setCellFormula("SUM(X1:Xn)");
```

Comment: you can use this "cell.getRawValue();" return type is String

Comment: Try reading (shock horror!) the [Apache POI website on evaluating formulas](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html)?